# Using argparse to create custom command line formats

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I realize that the question is rather general but I didn't know exactly how to ask it for what I am doing, but here goes.

I want to create a tool that allows option in the following format which also uses custom actions:

```
tool.py {start|stop|restart|configure}
```

Each of the above commands are mutually exclusive and some can have separate unique options. All will call a custom action (subclassed argparse.Action).

```
tool.py start
```

The above will do nothing because no arguments (via "add_argument()") was defined.

I though about making a subparser, but doing so doesn't work initially unless you set default arguments, via "set_defaults()". However, doing this and setting:

```
class CustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print('Args: %r %r %r' % (namespace, values, option_string))
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(help="Basic daemon.")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
start_parser = subparsers.add_parser("start")
start_parser.set_defaults(start=True, action=CustomAction)
```

doesn't seem to kick off the custom action as expected. Below is the output I get:

```
$ custom_parser.py start
Namespace(action=<class '__main__.BasicAction'>, start=True)
```

I can see that the values are being assigned, but NOT called.

I basically want to have **exclusive** parent options that can be specified **without** child argument but still allow **exclusive sub-arguments** like so, if desired:

```
tool.py configure {interval|recipients}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The documentation show two ways of using the subcommand to invoke a particular function.  One is `setdefaults` to set a `func` attribute, with is then called via `args.func(args)`.  The other is with a `subparsers` `dest`. This sets the subcommand name in `args`, which you can then use with a table lookup to invoke the desired command.

Comment: The default, however set, never calls an action.  `set_defaults` is in effect at `setattr()` command.  That is what you see in the `Namespace` - `start` and `action` attributes are set to their respective boolean and class values.  If you want to call a function, that has to be done after `parse_args`.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with setdefaults. You dont need to specify a new variable `start`. Also nothing is happening because you're not asking for anything to happen. You are just setting a variable to a hash named BasicAction. Just because you called the start subparser doesnt mean that argparse is going to execute your function, you have to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subparsers coupled with default functions

```py
def start_something():
    do_starting_actions()

def stop_something():
    do_terminal_actions()

def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    start = subparsers.add_parser("start")
    start.set_defaults(func=start_something)
    stop = subparsers.add_parser("stop")
    stop.set_defaults(func=stop_something)
    # ...
    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    args.func()
```

Then you can call the parser from the command line

```
mymodule.py start
```

If you wanted to extend the subparser you could do it like:

```
start = subparsers.add_parser("start")
start.add_argument("--foo")
```